# Left trim an std::vector without memory copy

Tags: c++, vector

Let's say we read a big 100MB file into memory like so:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> paddedName = { '0', '0', '0', 'T', 'O', 'M'/*... 100MB+ of data ... */ };
```

How can I trim out the first three characters and have a new vector with the padded data while discarding the old vector data?

Here is what the copy operation would look like:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> unpaddedName(paddedName.begin() + 3, paddedName.end());
```

But we obviously don't want to copy 100MB of memory just to erase 3 characters from beginning.

So is there a better way to do this?

Comment: an array reference class

Comment: Use a deque instead.

Comment: As Mike Seymour said, you can't do this with vector, or any contiguous block of memory.  However, you could just *refer* to it by a pointer to the 3rd element.  The memory is still there but it may not be worthwhile to shuffle 100MB just to shave off 3 bytes.

Comment: Either use a lightweight view class that starts from the index you desire in the vector or discard the bytes before loading them into the vector. Another possibility is writing a simple yet slow function that shifts all elements in the vector towards the beginning

Comment: @Rufflewind: You can do it with a contiguous memory block, if you maintain a separate pointer to the start of the valid data, as well as to the end as `vector` does. There's just no standard container that does that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I'm talking about deallocation of the 3 characters, not just shifting the pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it has to be `vector`, then you can't. A vector maintains a contiguous array, and only allows you to adjust its size (adding or removing from the end), not its starting point, so that adding or removing from the start requires moving the remaining elements.

You might use a `deque`, which allows removal from both ends. Or you might arrange to skip unwanted characters while reading them into the vector, rather than removing them later. Or you might maintain your own pointer/iterator to the start of the valid data, and use that instead of `paddedName.begin()`. You could generalise that to a "view" class, containing a pair of pointers/iterators to represent a subrange of the underlying vector, and use that to access just the data you want.